# prevent Page refresh after pop-up

Tags: javascript, asp.net

How can i prevent page refresh when the user clicks on  the `OK` button of the `javascript alert` window.

```
 <asp:Button ID="btnComplete" runat="server" Text="Complete" OnClientClick ="verify_complete()" />


 function verify_complete() {
        if (!chkCmnts()) {
            alert("Categories/comments are required. ");
            return false;
                         }
                             }
```

Thanks

BB

Answer (score 1):

You are already returning false from the JS so you need to change your markup to:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnComplete" runat="server" Text="Complete" OnClientClick ="return verify_complete()" />
```

If the `verify_complete()` function returns `true` it will post back, if it doesn't, it won't.

Answer (score 0):

You can not prevent this, but you can notify the user via a popup that he should not reload. This is done with the onbeforeunload window event, best documented at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onbeforeunload).

add this to your popup window in a Script-Tag

```
var controllVar = 1;
```

add this to your parent window. (popup is the return of `window.open(...)`). Here is actually some intensive error testing, because IE in it's various flavours shows more than one Bug.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
  //here we try accessing the popup
  try {
      if(!popup && popup.controllVar != 1) {
          return;
      }
  } catch(e) {
     return;
  }

  e = e || window.event;

  // For IE and Firefox prior to version 4
  if (e) {
    e.returnValue = 'YOUR ERROR MESSAGE';
  }

  // For Safari
  return 'YOUR ERROR MESSAGE';
};
```

This will behave exactly like here on Stackoverflow, if you add some text to the answer textarea and than try to leave the page.